# APFS Container Scheme Size +ERROR after power outage (Mojave)

Tags: disk-utility, partition, mojave, error, apfs

My mac would not boot after a power outage.

Connected the drive to an older iMac and am trying to troubleshoot.

I ran >diskutil list . The problem drive is /dev/disk2. It shows APFS container scheme +ERROR in SIZE and will on mount or boot.

Currently running DD to clone the drive "as is".

```
cv@Jennifers-iMac ~ % diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk1⁩         1.0 TB     disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +1.0 TB     disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume ⁨Macintosh HD - Data⁩     550.0 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume ⁨Preboot⁩                 275.9 MB   disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume ⁨Recovery⁩                1.1 GB     disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume ⁨VM⁩                      2.1 GB     disk1s4
   5:                APFS Volume ⁨Macintosh HD⁩            15.4 GB    disk1s5
   6:              APFS Snapshot ⁨com.apple.os.update-...⁩ 15.4 GB    disk1s5s1

/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk2
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk3⁩         499.9 GB   disk2s2

/dev/disk3 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +ERROR      disk3
                                 Physical Store disk2s2
   1:                APFS Volume ⁨MeenasMusic⁩             ERROR      disk3s1
   2:                APFS Volume ⁨Preboot⁩                 ERROR      disk3s2
   3:                APFS Volume ⁨Recovery⁩                ERROR      disk3s3
   4:                APFS Volume ⁨VM⁩                      ERROR      disk3s4

/dev/disk4 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk4
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     209.7 MB   disk4s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk5⁩         2.0 TB     disk4s2

/dev/disk5 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +2.0 TB     disk5
                                 Physical Store disk4s2
   1:                APFS Volume ⁨SAMPLES NANKU⁩           819.2 KB   disk5s1
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.